# atomic multi node updates with validation dependency between them

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am trying to update multiple nodes together atomically using `ref().update`

sample below is a modified version of the [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/save-data#update_specific_fields) on `update` with multiple children

So when a user creates a post, the code will atomically do the following

- Update `/app-user/$uid/lastpost_timestamp` to firebase server timestamp (for rate limiting purposes)
- Create the new post under /posts/$postid with same timestamp
- Create user reference posts in /user-posts/$uid/$postid with same timestamp

JS Code

```
function writeNewPost(uid, username, picture, title, body) {
  // A post entry.
  var postData = {
    author: username,
    uid: uid,
    body: body,
    title: title,
    starCount: 0,
    authorPic: picture,
    timestamp:firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
  };

  // Get a key for a new Post.
  var newPostKey = firebase.database().ref().child('posts').push().key;

  // Write the new post's data simultaneously in the posts list and the user's post list.
  var updates = {};
  updates['/users/' + uid + '/lastpost_timestamp'] = firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
  updates['/posts/' + newPostKey] = postData;
  updates['/user-posts/' + uid + '/' + newPostKey] = postData;

  return firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
}
```

This is working fine until I map dependencies in `database.json` to ensure

- `/users/$uid/lastposttime_timestamp` should be `now`
- `/posts/$post/timestamp` should match `lastposttime_timestamp`
- In `/users-posts/$uid/$post`, $post should exists in `/posts` before linking to `/user-posts/`

Snippet of database security rules:

```
"users":{
  "$user":{
    "lastpost_timestamp":{
      ".write":"auth.uid == $user && newData.exists()"
        ".validate":"newData.val() == now && ((data.exists() && data.val() + 60000 < newData.val() )|| !data.exists())"
    }
  }
},
"posts":{
    "$post":{
      "timestamp":{
        ".validate":"newData.val() == now && newData.val() == root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('lastpost_timestamp').val()"
      }
    }
},
"user-posts":{
  "$uid":{
    "$post":{
      ".write":"auth.uid == $uid && newData.exists()"
      ".validate":"root.child('posts').child($post).exists()"
    }
  }
}
```

Since these updates occur together, the validation rules fail because I am validating referenced node which are part of the same update using `root` references like `root.child('posts').child($post).exists()` which causes it to fail. Without these `root`references, I am able to update the nodes together.

I can run these separately but then update's atomic benefits disappear when chaining the updates using promises and adding each dependent update on the next `.then`. This would also mean that timestamps won't match and I would have to check if each operation for rollbacks.

Any idea if I am doing something wrong or if this is not supported.

Comment: Did you check which specific rule fails? I expect that it's the `root` references, in which case I recently answered a similar case and will look it up.

Comment: yes, any reference to data which is also being inserted using `root` references like `root.child('posts').child($post).exists()` causes it to fail. without it the operation succeeds.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen -  I think this is the [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39179650/firebase-multi-location-rules-same-value/39183242#39183242) your were pointing to. I will checkout if this works in my scenario. Thanks

Comment: Yup, that was the one indeed. Apologies for the number of `parent()` calls that you have to write.

Comment: so just to understand, does `root` only look at data which is already present in firebase and using references of `newData.parent()` would look at both existing and new data which is being inserted muck like how newData behaves.

Comment: `root` and `data` refer to the data as it exists before the write operation, `newData` refers to the data as it will exist after the write operation (if that operation succeeds).